# Safari Extension: How to know if popup is enabled

Tags: safari, safari-extension

My extension will behave differently when popups are enabled, how would i find this out through the global/html? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If popovers are not available, then `safari.extension.popovers` will be undefined.